# How to display a phone number from database, exchanging digit for a hash "#"

Tags: php

See if anyone can help me with this. I Think it's pretty simple, but since I'm new at programming I'm having a hard time.

I need to display a phone number from a location on a HTML table, this location is selected by the user on a dropdown. But I was asked to exchange the last digit from the telephone with a hash "#".

Is there any way I can do this with PHP? Any help or example will be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please research yourself how to manipulate strings in php. It's hard to beleive that you cannot find a feasible tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Just I think that you have to remove the last character and then add what you want to the number, like:

```
$string = "123456789";  // Original Number
$replacement = "#";    // What you want to replace the last character with

// The final string
$final = substr($string, 0, -1).$replacement;
```

The result will be : 
12345678#

Answer (score 0):

try to reverse the number, then replace the first with `#`, reverse again. Voila. Its a little hacky but it was off the top of my head:

```
 echo strrev(substr_replace ( strrev("07756727368897") , '#' , 0, 1)) ;
```

Comment: y'd rather explain why your code snippet would solve his problem.

Comment: reverse the number, replace the first with #, reverse again. Voila. Its a little hacky but it was off the top of my head

Comment: Thank you, but next time you have to include the explanation in the answer itself as your answer was flagged ass low quality answer. Anyway I added your explanation in your answer.

Comment: Thanks Muhammed (thumbs up)